# Accessing method in another Swift file in AppDelegate

Tags: ios, swift

Here is my settings.swift file :

```
import Foundation

class Settings {

    func setDefaultSettings()  {
    }
}
```

I would like to access the function in AppDelegate `didFinishLaunchingWithOptions`. I've tried calling

`Settings.setDefaultSettings()` but it didn't work.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You have two ways to make this work:

1.Initialise object of Settings class

```
Settings().setDefaultSettings()
```

or

```
let settings = Settings()
settings.setDefaultSettings()
```

2.Make the function static

```
static func setDefaultSettings(){...}
```

in this case you can call it your way

```
Settings.setDefaultSettings()
```

Comment: Thanks it works. However I'm getting an error. Use of unresolved identifier 'Settings'. But it still runs with no problems

Comment: Try to mark your class Settings as `public`. May be this will resolve the issue.

Answer (score 1):

Method can be defined in two ways : Instance method and class Methods
You have declared the method as Instance method, which can accessible through the instance of the class. So, to access the methods needs instance of the class, which can be created as

```
let settingObj = Settings()
settingObj.setDefaultSettings()

-------------------------------------------------

//Combined statement
Settings().setDefaultSettings()
```

and `class method` can be written using the keyword `static` or `class`. They can be access by the class name itself. Please see the example below

```
class Settings {

    class func setDefaultSettings()  
    {
        print("Default Settings")
    }
}
```

Now you can call the method directly by the class name

```
Settings.setDefaultSettings()
```

Comment: A explanation, what the problem is and why your answer is a solution, would be nice.

Comment: Sorry, i do not understand, Is my answer accurate or i need to add some explanation?

Comment: It is correct, but a good answer should explain what the error was and why your solution is correct.

Answer (score 0):

You can access this method as follow

1) Create one Class  of NSObject as follow.(GLOBAL.swift)

```
class GLOBAL : NSObject {

    //sharedInstance
    static let sharedInstance = GLOBAL()
}
```

2) Define your method here.

```
class GLOBAL : NSObject {

    //sharedInstance
    static let sharedInstance = GLOBAL()

    func setDefaultSettings()  {

    }
}
```

3) Use above method as follow.

```
GLOBAL.sharedInstance.setDefaultSettings()
```

You can also use this `setDefaultSettings()` in setting class and also any other class.

Comment: You pressed the caps-lock key incidentally. ;-) Please respect the naming conventions for both Swift and Objective-C.